# Host Discovery on LAN using non blocking connect

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to check for an host on a network by performing an non-blocking connect and then performing an select to see whether the socket is writable or under-exceptions .I try to establish an socket connection over the ports 80,139 .The host will be discoverable if the socket is writable after connect or when it goes to exceptions when the host sends an RST pack et.

I had written an code using windows sockets and the logic worked fine ,but using linux sockets the program is not giving the desired results .The select function returns 1 for any given ip address's even though  there are no hosts on that ip .The select would have timed out on the winsock's case returning an 0.I have written the code below ,let me know where exactly is the problem.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int port[]={80,139};

void Free(int Sock_Arr[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        close(Sock_Arr[i]);
    }
    return ;
}

int  main()
{
    int Socket[2],result=0; //Socket array
    struct sockaddr_in service;


    fd_set writefds;
    fd_set exceptfds;


    struct timeval timer;
    timer.tv_sec=5;

    timer.tv_usec=0;

    int flag=0;

    FD_ZERO(&writefds);
    FD_ZERO(&exceptfds);


    char Ip_Addr[20];
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        if((Socket[i]=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP)) < 0)
        {
             Free(Socket);
        }
        fcntl(Socket[i],F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);



    }

    bzero(&service, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

    printf("Enter the ip-address : ");
    scanf("%s",Ip_Addr);



    service.sin_family=AF_INET;
    service.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(Ip_Addr);



    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {


        FD_SET(Socket[i],&writefds);
        FD_SET(Socket[i],&exceptfds);
        service.sin_port=htons((unsigned short int )port[i]);
        connect(Socket[i],(struct sockaddr *)&service,sizeof(sockaddr_in));



        result= select(Socket[i]+1,NULL,&writefds,&exceptfds,&timer);

        if(result<0||result==0)
        {
                flag=0;
                printf("\n The machine could not be found on the port %d ",port[i]);
                printf("result : %d",result);
                perror("select");

        }
        else
        {

                printf("\n The machine could  be found on the port %d ",port[i]);
                flag=1;
                printf("result : %d",result);

                if(FD_ISSET(Socket[i],&writefds))
                {
                    printf("The socket triggered on write on port %d",port[i]);
                }

                else if(FD_ISSET(Socket[i],&exceptfds))
                {
                    printf("The socket triggered on except on port %d",port[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("No socket triggered on %d",port[i]);
                }

        }

        FD_ZERO(&writefds);
        FD_ZERO(&exceptfds);



    }

    Free(Socket);

    if(flag==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }



}
```

Comment: A bit off topic but still: 1) Don't use `bzero`, use `memset`. 2) You don't pass arrays to functions, you pass pointer(s) to array(s). 3) Don't use function names like `Free` (or `Close` or whatever can easily be mistaken for standard calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
result= select(Socket[i],NULL,&writefds,&exceptfds,&timer);
```

the first argument to `select` should be the largest file descriptor you want to `select()` on + 1. As you are only l You are not adding 1 and that could cause a problem. Try

```
result= select(Socket[i]+1,NULL,&writefds,&exceptfds,&timer);
```

You would be better off actually NOT having a loop over your sockets and add ALL the socket file descriptors to the fd_sets, working out the largest file descriptor, perform all the non blocking `connect` calls and **then** use your select call just once to check for socket activity on any of them (using the largest file descriptor +1 as the first argument to select). Then if `select()` returns positive you can use `FD_ISSET` to identify what socket caused `select()` to trigger; This way you can use `select()` to look for activity over many sockets at once. This is how I do things when I am listening for activity on multiple sockets.

At the very least you should probably clear your fd_set each time you iterate over your second loop in which you perform the `connect()` calls as you are not removing the socket fds that you added in previous iterations and so you may be looking for activity on other sockets in addition to the currently added one.

Also, doing this in the way you are doing, you are not resetting your timeout values you send to the `select()` call. From the `select` man pages it clearly states that `select` **may** change the timeout value. Thus if this is the case it is possible that your timeout has been reduced by subsequent iteration calls to `select` try resetting the timeout to 5 seconds at each iteration also. If the timeout has been reduced so much that it is zero, then the select() call will return instantly (polling).

Comment: i did that too ,but didn't work.It is returning one for everything.

Comment: I have edited and pasted the code as above ,now the select is always returning true on the first port but not on the second port .I have done the steps as per your suggestion.

Comment: Did what you have said sir and it has worked like a charm.Brilliant.